# Cast from Object back to Generic

Tags: c#, generics, windows-runtime

I want to pass some PageDefinitions to a new Windows RT Page.

The PageDefinition:

```
class PageDefinition<T> where T: IItem { ... }
```

I pass it like this:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Overview), new PageDefinition<AnItem>)
```

And then in the new Page I want to get the Informations out of my arguments. The LoadState-Method of the pages is predefined as this:

```
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
```

But how do I cast the navigationParameter back to my original Type? I tried the following, but this doesn't work (pageDefinition stays null)

```
var pageDefinition = navigationParameter as PageDefinition<IItem>;
```

Can't I cast back from to the original type?

Would appreciate you help as I looked around but couldn't find something helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the as operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions.The as operator cannot perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: I now do it this way:
Type type = navigationParameter.GetType();
this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = type.GetRuntimeProperty("Groups").GetValue(navigationParameter);
=> Definitely not a clean way, don't even know if Reflections are allowed in Windows Store Apps :( Still listening to you tipps!

Comment: PageDefinition<IItem> isn't your original type, PageDefinition<AnItem> is, and that will work.  If you changed your var pageDefinition to PageDefinition<AnItem> you would also see a casting exception.

Comment: This would not be possible as I don't know which type it really is, I only now it implements IItem, this could also be AnotherItem. Maybe it is not possible, i was just trying to find out if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim already mentioned in the comment, the following cast is not allowed in C# with `PageDefinition<T>` being defined as in your question:

```
var def = (PageDefinition<IItem>)new PageDefinition<AnItem>();
```

This would require a generic class to be cast to a generic class with less derived generic argument. If you cast your `navigationParameter` to `PageDefinition<AnItem>` instead, it will work as expected.

Alternatively you could take advantage of support for [covariant generic interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx) and make your conversion work if you really need it. You'll need to declare (notice the `out` keyword):

```
interface IPageDefinition<out T> where T: IItem { }
```

And then:

```
class PageDefinition<T> : IPageDefinition<T> where T: IItem
```

After doing this the following cast will work:

```
var def = (IPageDefinition<IItem>)new PageDefinition<AnItem>();
```

There are limitations to the usage of T in the interface (basically you can only use it as return type), so you'll have to check if you can make it work for you. Details are described in the linked article.

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to be what I need! I'll try to implement it and then come back to you! Thanks in advance!